# Strange cell formatting issue in datagridview vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I have a `datagridview` that when I use the following code:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(RowNum).Cells("TotalTime").Value = "12:34:--"
```

I would expect the display to show "12:34:--" in the grid cell, but instead for some reason it displays "--:12:34" in the cell.  I have tried all kinds of things and it appears the problem is with the "--" (two hyphens).  If I try this code:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(RowNum).Cells("TotalTime").Value = "12:34:00"
```

It works perfect and the display is "12:34:00" as you would expect. Does anyone have any ideas why this is?

Comment: Did you by chance set `DataGridView1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes` either in the designer or via code?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "TotalTime")
    Dim RowNum As Integer = 0
    DataGridView1.Rows(RowNum).Cells("Col1").Value = "12:34:--"
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear all formatting from the column and try again.